# Following Railscast #102 on Rails 4 - Autocomplete_source won't work, but local list does

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm following Railscast 102 to implement autocomplete in my site, but the autocomplete_source part doesn't work.

[image: The text field]

[image: Post.rb]

[image: Post.js]

[image: Not autocompleting]

[image: But the categories are being filled out though.]

Any help? I'm on Rails 4, which is what I suspect is messing this up. I'd like to let the user choose the category, if it doesn't exist, make one and it gets saved to db so the next user can choose that category.

Note, if I do this it works:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see your pain since I recently started learning rails. The problem is not in rails 4, but actually your source. This line of code does not work properly:

```
source: $('#post_category_name').autocomplete
```

The link below goes deeper into autocomplete and even helps you speed up the query using redis which is pretty fast. Ryan also includes rake tasks to help reindex the tables in your database
[Autocomplete Pro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMz8HmrQ350)

I suggest you spend time looking at this video. It would help a lot.

Comment: I've watched it but it didn't really help me. I'm new to Rails as well.